# maintaining the state of checkbox while moving across xhtml pages

Tags: html, checkbox, xhtml

I have a `xhtml` page which has a `checkbox` as one of the elements. I have created the `checkbox` using:

```
<td align="right" width="1%"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="#{checkState.val}" /></td>
```

Now what I want is that if a user checks this `checkbox` and then moves to some another page by clicking some buttons which are also on the same html page as this checkbox is, and if the user returns back to this page again then the state of the `checkbox` should remain checked. Thus I want to preserve the state of the `checkbox`. In short, I am on `page1` which has the `checkbox`, I check this `checkbox`, move to page2, do some stuff and return back to page 1 then the `checkbox` should be checked. If did not checked the `checkbox` initially then it should not be checked when I return.

I am very new to `xhtml` and have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Although it is not specified in the question tag, you might want to explore using JS to set a cache that stores the state of that checkbox. Also, [XHTML has been officially abandoned in favour of HTML5](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5).

Comment: Also you could store the data in a file by sending ajax call to the server or if you have db set up you could store value there and when page loads get the state of the checkbox from the server.

Comment: @Maxqueue can you give an example of the database method?

Comment: @Maxqueue I mean if you explain it through an example in form of an answer. I am new to this whole html/xhtml stuff and thus its easier for me to understand it through some example

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is the html side where you would make a call to getCheckBoxData.php which lives on the server
    function load()
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
            {
                document.getElementById("checkbox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getCheckBoxData.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    //this is your php on the back end
    $con=mysqli_connect(connection::url(),connection::user(),connection::pas(),connection::dbName());
    $session=new session();
    $session->startSession();
    $query = "SELECT checkboxfield FROM checkboxtable;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $value= $row['checkboxfield'];
    echo $value;//This sends text back to the client and will be in the response text above.
```

This is an example using php with MySQL db set up on the server. In this case your checkbox field could pass back the text "checked" or "unchecked" and you could put that value in when your page loads. Hope this helps

Comment: Is it possible if you could provide an example which involves only `xhtlm`, `jsf`, a normal java class and DB? Actually the application I am working on does not support `php` or `server`

Comment: No sorry don't have an example of what your looking for. However if the only state you care about is the checkbox then file io might be your best bet. Good luck